# Delayed response from Tomcat backend to Apache HTTPD reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, apache, websocket, httpd.conf, http2

We have a setup with:

1. Apache HTTPD 2.4.57 acting as a reverse proxy, listening on port 4443
2. Springboot (tomcat) backend , listening on port 9085

both of them are installed on the **same box**.

Apache HTTPD has HTTP/2 enabled & SSL enabled.
Springboot doesn't have http2 enabled, but it has HTTPS enabled (weird, but that's the policy from our security guy, unfortunately). Springboot serves both REST api as well as websocket

Apache HTTPD configuration looks like this, roughly:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
   StartServers 3
   MinSpareThreads 75
   MaxSpareThreads 250
   ThreadsPerChild 25
   MaxRequestWorkers 2500
   ServerLimit 100
   MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost _default_:4443>
  SSLSessionTickets off
  SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
  ProxyTimeout 300
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "..."
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "..."

  ProxyRequests Off
  
  #for websocket 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
  RequestHeader set Upgrade websocket
  RewriteRule /api/backend/(.*) wss://backendurl:9085/$1 [P,L]

  #for REST
  <LocationMatch "^/api/backend/(.*)">
     ProxyPassMatch "https://backendurl:9085/$1" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
     ProxyPassReverse "https://backendurl:9085/$1"
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </LocationMach>

  #for other backend
  <LocationMatch "^/api/backend2/(.*)">
     ProxyPassMatch "https://backendurl:8085/$1" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
     ProxyPassReverse "https://backendurl:8085/$1"
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </LocationMach>

</VirtualHost>
```

We have around 200 users, and each user will open about 6 websocket connections in addition to regular REST calls. The websocket connections will get torn down every 5 minutes by apache 'ProxyTimeout' setting (and the UI will re-establish the connections). Not 100% sure why this was done - the only info I can get from my predecessors were 'to keep the connection fresh'.

What we noticed is that occasionally, our users request seems to be stuck on the way back from Springboot backend back to Apache HTTPD. E.g. we have something like this in apache access log:

```
2023-08-31 07:00:00.000 PUT /api/backend/someEndpoint 200 - 50000 HTTP/2.0 10.125.200.54 1
```

where:

1. 2023-08-31 07:00:00.000 is the time user request arrived on apache
   reverse proxy
2. PUT is the HTTP method
3. /api/backend/someEndpoint is the URL requested by user
4. 200 is response status
5. "-"  is nothing, because PUT didn't return anything
6. 50000 is the request duration  (50 seconds)
7. HTTP/2.0 is the protocol
8. 10.125.200.54 is the user IP
9. 1 is the keep alive (not 100% sure about this, actually)

meanwhile, if we look at the corresponding entry in our springboot log, we will find that that particular request arrived there roughly on the same millis (expected, as it is on the same box), but the request was served within a few seconds at most, definitely far less than 50 seconds as perceived by HTTPD.

Now.. that is based on my assumption that 50 seconds is the time between apache HTTPD -> tomcat -> apache HTTPD (i.e. it doesn't include the time it takes to write back to client). Am I right on this? If it in fact includes the time to write back to the client, then there seems to be a big delay in the network itself (between client and apache, which makes more sense to me - see my note at the bottom of this post, where we also occasionally see a big delay between request sent by client & request received at apache HTTPD).

Note that our apache log format is:

```
"%{%Y-%m-%d %T}t.%{msec_frac}t %m %U %>s %b %{ms}T %H %h %k"
```

So we are not sure what could cause this delay on the way back to apache httpd. The approach I have taken so far (to try to reproduce the issue in our test environments, using Jmeter test) are:

1. Setting iobuffersize and receivebuffersize for the 'ProxyPassMatch' to 512 (the absolute minimum number). My thought was, the default buffer size in production is not big enough, hence response was stalled on the way back from spring boot.
2. Disabling http2, and went back to http1 (we used to run on http1)

So far we couldn't reproduce the production issue in the test environment. We didn't see any delay between tomcat and apache.

Meanwhile (a second, yet related issue) - some of our users are also experiencing long delay between their browser connections & apache. Their requests arrive very late on the apache HTTPD itself.

Is there any obvious wrong configuration in our apache settings above? Any help is much appreciated!